# I want a drop down option will be selected in class=item_circle and save it in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want a drop down option will be selected in `class=item_circle` and save it in 
     MySQL. Is there any answer? I'm getting single data in MySQL
     database but not the selected one:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="crud_table">
 <tr>
  <th width="10%">CIRCLE</th>
  <th width="10%">Item1</th>
  <th width="10%">Item1</th>
  <th width="10%">Item1</th>
  <th width="10%">Item1</th>
  <th width="2%"></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="item_circle">Bus Stand</td>
  <td contenteditable="true" name="amt" class="item_1"></td>
  <td contenteditable="true" name="amt" class="item_2"></td>
  <td contenteditable="true" name="amt" class="item_3"></td>
  <td contenteditable="true" name="amt" class="item_4"></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: there is no drop down

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you've asked for (because sorry but your question is a little bit cryptic), but you can just send the data you want to write into the database by either an AJAX request, or, in the case of a drop-down menu as you said, by assigning a value-attribute to each dropdown entry and then sending that via a form to the backend script.